# With Git how ignore node_modules on commit

Tags: angular, git, visual-studio-code

I'd like not commit the folder "node_modules"

I tried several solutions found around the web :

1. Create a file .gitignore (placed in the route of my application at same level than .git folder)
2. In this file I tried : node_modules and /node_modules/ and that /node_modules/** and that node_modules/**

When I do `npm install` this folder and all the packages are added to the file to commit and I get a warning from Visual Studio code because there are 5000 elements to commit.

Any idea ?

Comment: In your .gitignore: `/node_modules`

Comment: @bugs I just tried again and still not ignored. Is it something to do avec .gitignore file creation ?

Comment: Is `node_modules` at the same level as your `.gitignore` ?

Comment: I create the .gitignore with GitBash and now that's work. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .gitignore file and add `node_modules/` if `node_modules/` was added to your repository then you need to delete or .gitignote doesn't work.

Comment: To elaborate, if `node_modules/` was already added to your repository in a previous commit, you must `git rm --cached node_modules/`. The `--cached` flag makes the command only remove the folder in the staging area, not in your working directory.